# htacess redirect an external directory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm building a Wordpress site and I want to change the url of an external directory with .htaccess because I don't want my repository's name to be in the url.

The url of the external directory is

> "http://localhost:10012/wordpress_externaldirectory/lp/sample"

I want to change this url to

> "http://localhost:10012/lp/sample"

So, I wrote this in my htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^wordpress-externaldirectory/(.*)$ //$1 [R=301,L]
```

I expected that if you hit /lp/sample, you can access /wordpress_externaldirectory/lp/sample", but it did not work.

does anyone have an idea why it is not working?
thanks in advance

Comment: Because you are doing it the wrong way around. The first argument of RewriteRule is the pattern to match the request URL against.

Comment: ah I got it thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You only went half of the way. You only redirected requests using the "old" URL. You forgot to internally rewrite requests to the "new" URL, to map those the the actual internal ressource ...

Have a try along these lines:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?wordpress-externaldirectory/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wordpress-externaldirectory/
RewriteRule ^ /wordpress-externaldirectory%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Comment: okay so it redirects from "http://localhost:10012/lp/sample" to "http://localhost:10012/wordpress_externaldirectory/lp/sample"

I'm wondering if it is possible to only internally map the urls? I want to cut the /wordpress_externaldirectory part out from the new url

Comment: Like when I hit "localhost:10012/lp/sample" I want the url to point to "localhost:10012/wordpress_externaldirectory/lp/sample" but still keep the url

Comment: WordPress itself has PHP to canonicalize the URL.   Implementing rewrite rules without touching WordPress settings is unlikely to work.